# Using Windows XCOPY on Buildbot worker

Tags: xcopy, buildbot

I am using Buildbot 2.4.0 and I need to copy files from one folder on the worker to another folder on the same worker, just copying files around.
I am struggling to use xcopy, basically it does not work.

```
from buildbot.plugins import steps

f.addStep(steps.ShellCommand(command=["cmd.exe /k", "xcopy Y:\sourcefile\j93n.exe Y:\dest\folder"],
                             workdir="build/directory"))
```

Does anyone have a working example of how I can use xcopy to copy files around on the worker?
Is this the correct way to call xcopy.
I'm using Windows

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
f.addStep(steps.ShellCommand(command=["cmd.exe /k", "xcopy Y:\sourcefile\j93n.exe Y:\dest\folder\"],
                             workdir="build/directory"))
```

since the destination is a folder, you should add a backslash at the end.
I don't know hot to escape in Buildbot worker, but if you know the escape char you can use it to enclose both source and destination in double quotes. For example:

```
f.addStep(steps.ShellCommand(command=["cmd.exe /k", "xcopy \"Y:\sourcefile\j93n.exe\" \"Y:\dest\folder\\""],
                             workdir="build/directory"))
```

But... if backslash is the escape char, then the problem is another... The paths should have been written differently.